# How to prevent QTableWidget from occupying the whole window in a QHBoxLayout?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

In my Qt program, I programmatically generate a  modal QDialog. I want to show two widgets in this dialog window: A custom widget showing a camera output and a QTableWidget, showing the pixel coordinates of the corners found in the camera image. I generate a QHBoxLayout and add my custom widget and the QTableWidget into it. Then I set this QHBoxLayout as the Layout of the QDialog window. What I want to achieve is to share the available space in the QDialog's window area equally between my custom QWidget and the QTableWidget, horizontally, by using a QHBoxLayout. But I always end up with QTableWidget occupying the whole QDialog area, by overlapping my custom widget. How can I instruct these two widgets to exactly share the QDialog area?? Note that I first add my custom widget and then the QTableWidget into the QHBoxLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure on your custom widget you've specified a `minimumSizeHint` and a `sizeHint`, this instructs the `QLayout` manager that the widget requires a specific space. To have them split equally you'll be best off detecting the size of the `QDialog` and then specifying the width for both by removing the boundary sizes (spacing between widgets + space to `QDialog` edge) and dividing it up.